How to prevent a sticky table header showing horizontally scrolled content in the border?
I want to prevent the red headers from showing in the blue header's border when scrolling horizontally. I must have a white border in the blue headers.


.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  background-color: red;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sticky {
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2;
}

.test1 {
  left: 0;
}

.test2 {
  left: 57px;
}

.test3 {
  left: 114px;
}
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky test1">
        Test1
        </th>
        <th class="sticky test2">
        Test2
        </th>
        <th class="sticky test3">
        Test3
        </th>
        <th>
        Test4
        </th>
        <th>
        Test5
        </th>
        <th>
        Test6
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>



I want to prevent the red headers from showing in the blue header's border when scrolling horizontally. I must have a white border in the blue headers.

You could remove all borders and use e a CSS pseudo-element on each header cell to fake the border effect...
Also, would suggest you fix the width of your sticky columns, that way you can set the left property a bit easier. I've gone ahead to use the exact width as I was getting tiny shifts (~1px) when using the horizontal scroll.


.container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 200px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.sticky {
    background-color: blue;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
}

th::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    /* Adjust fake border width here */
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.test1 {
    left: 0;
}

.test2 {
    left: 55.86px;
    /* this is the exact width of the column header */
}

.test3 {
    left: calc(55.86px * 2);
    /* made this exact to stop the tiny shifts when scrolling */
}
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sticky test1">
                    Test1
                </th>
                <th class="sticky test2">
                    Test2
                </th>
                <th class="sticky test3">
                    Test3
                </th>
                <th>
                    Test4
                </th>
                <th>
                    Test5
                </th>
                <th>
                    Test6
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>




The issue is being caused by border-collapse: collapse;
You will be more successful if you don't use a table.
I have replicated your desired output using divs with display:inline-flex. Notice, I have used only one div.sticky to wrap the sticky elements so there is no need to put exact left values for each individual item.


.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

div.headers,
div.sticky {
  display: inline-flex;
}

div.headers>div,
div.sticky>div {
  background-color: red;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.headers>div.sticky {
  padding: 0;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  z-index: 999;
}

div.sticky>div {
  background-color: blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class='headers'>
    <div class="sticky">
      <div>
        Test1
      </div>
      <div>
        Test2
      </div>
      <div>
        Test3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      Test4
    </div>
    <div>
      Test5
    </div>
    <div>
      Test6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I can't have a surrounding border and I need a 1px right border on the blue headers,  how can I achieve that without border-collapse?

@epatmalnieks Don't use a table (edited answer)

You can achieve this by adding a box-shadow to your sticky class as below
.sticky {
    ....
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 0px white;
}


Update sticky class with this :
  .sticky {
     background-color: blue;
     position: sticky;
     z-index: 2;
     border-spacing: 0 !important;
     outline: 1px solid white;
     border: unset;
  }

